# verify product key saved in database

Tags: php, html, database

I am designing a product registration system which accepts key as XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX which is already saved in database. I want to check if key register in database and if yes then it must enter the other fields as name, email id, contact number etc.
But i don't know how verify product key submitted by user because registration form contains code as follows:

```
 <tr>
    <td><span>Product Key:</span></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="productkey" onKeyUp="moveOnMax(this,productkey2)" size="4" maxlength="5" /> 
         - <input type="text" id="productkey2" onKeyUp="moveOnMax(this,productkey3)" size="4" maxlength="5" /> 
         - <input type="text" id="productkey3" onKeyUp="moveOnMax(this,productkey4)" size="4" maxlength="5"/> 
         - <input type="text" id="productkey4" size="4" maxlength="5"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Except Product key I know how to save rest information in database.

Comment: I don't really get your question, especially this part - `I know how to save all information in database but I don't have any idea about how to save Product key in database.`

Comment: now are you OK with the question?

Comment: Not really. What is keeping you from saving the product key into the database when you already know how to save data in database?

Comment: I wrote different code to save key in DB. Code I post above is for user form. I want to verify product key is right or not or it is already taken by any user.

Comment: So you want to do a comparison?

Comment: Yup. I am not getting how to do it because there are 4 text fields for product key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input type="text" id="productkey" name="first" onKeyUp="moveOnMax(this,productkey2)" size="4" maxlength="5" /> 
- <input type="text" name="second" id="productkey2" onKeyUp="moveOnMax(this,productkey3)" size="4" maxlength="5" /> 
- <input type="text" name="third" id="productkey3" onKeyUp="moveOnMax(this,productkey4)" size="4" maxlength="5"/> 
- <input type="text" name="fourth" id="productkey4" size="4" maxlength="5"/>
```

You'll need a `name` attribute for the textboxes since PHP uses that to identify input data. Then you can simply do

```
$userEnteredProductKey = $_POST['first'].'-'.$_POST['second'].'-'.$_POST['third'].'-'.$_POST['fourth'];
// $userEnteredProductKey will contain data in xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx format
```

And then use `$userEnteredProductKey` in the `WHERE` clause of your SQL query to compare the data.

Comment: I will try it. I have query about mySQL DB. I have table with me having fields id, name, key, email. I entered keys in DB already. Is it possible to enter rest all fields without changing key column? I mean I don't want to replace key value. Is it possible to do so?
I am sorry for my English :D

Comment: I used above code. But it fails to check whether Product Key is already present in DB or not. I am using query as `SELECT key FROM license_key WHERE key ='$userEnteredProductKey'`

Comment: Try and echo `userEnteredProductKey` and see if indeed is capturing user input

Comment: It captures user input, but I am unable to compare it.

Answer (score 0):

I have weak php knowledge but I hope that will helps you

```
<?php
////// Post Data from HTML Form
$serialNumber = $_POST['prodectkey'];

////// Your Database Connection Informaiton
$DB_HostName = "127.0.0.1";
$DB_Name = "products";
$DB_User = "root";
$DB_Pass = "root";
$DB_Table = "serial";


////// Connection Happen Here
$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prodects where key=$serialNumber");
$column = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $column[] = $row['key'];
   $conted = count($column);

}
if ($conted == 1) {
  echo "Done I could find it in the database";
}else{
echo "I couldn't find it :(";
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: this code may work. But i don't have single text field for product key. That's why I can't use this code.